# How to set up multi-face recognition with ARKit3?

Tags: arkit

I am trying to develop the `ARKit3` facial recognition application. I want to make an application that supports multi-face recognition. I have made the following settings, but it does not work. Is it wrong with me?

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        /// SetupDelegate
        faceSCNView.delegate = self
        faceSCNView.session.delegate = self

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        /// FaceTrackingConfiguration
        let configuration = ARFaceTrackingConfiguration()

        /// MaxNumberOfTrackedFaces = 2
        configuration.maximumNumberOfTrackedFaces = 2

        /// Run
        faceSCNView.session.run(configuration)
    }
```

**Delegate**

```
extension GameViewController : ARSCNViewDelegate {

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

        print(anchor.sessionIdentifier , anchor.identifier , anchor.name)

        if anchor is ARFaceAnchor {
            print("renderer didAdd", anchor.identifier , anchor.name ?? "noname")
        }
    }

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        guard
            let faceAnchor = anchor as? ARFaceAnchor
            else { return}

        print("renderer didUpdate", faceAnchor.identifier , faceAnchor.blendShapes[.mouthClose] ?? 0)
    }
}

extension GameViewController : ARSessionDelegate {

    func session(_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor]) {

      print(anchors.count)
        for anchor in anchors where anchor is ARFaceAnchor {

            let faceAnchor = anchor as! ARFaceAnchor

            print("Session didAdd", faceAnchor.identifier , faceAnchor.blendShapes[.mouthClose] ?? 0)
        }
    }

    func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]) {

        for anchor in anchors where anchor is ARFaceAnchor {

            let faceAnchor = anchor as! ARFaceAnchor

            print("Session didUpdate", faceAnchor.identifier , faceAnchor.blendShapes[.mouthClose] ?? 0)

        }
    }

}
```

No matter how many people perform facial recognition together, there is only one recognized Anchor, the identifier is: `CA831DB2-E078-45C3-9A1C-44F8459AA04F`.

```
renderer didUpdate CA831DB2-E078-45C3-9A1C-44F8459AA04F 0.04505286
Session didUpdate CA831DB2-E078-45C3-9A1C-44F8459AA04F 0.04578292
renderer didUpdate CA831DB2-E078-45C3-9A1C-44F8459AA04F 0.04813192
Session didUpdate CA831DB2-E078-45C3-9A1C-44F8459AA04F 0.04813192
Session didUpdate CA831DB2-E078-45C3-9A1C-44F8459AA04F 0.04832877
Session didUpdate CA831DB2-E078-45C3-9A1C-44F8459AA04F 0.0484867
renderer didUpdate CA831DB2-E078-45C3-9A1C-44F8459AA04F 0.0484867
renderer didUpdate CA831DB2-E078-45C3-9A1C-44F8459AA04F 0.04869337
Session didUpdate CA831DB2-E078-45C3-9A1C-44F8459AA04F 0.04869337
Session didUpdate CA831DB2-E078-45C3-9A1C-44F8459AA04F 0.0489419
renderer didUpdate CA831DB2-E078-45C3-9A1C-44F8459AA04F 0.05000613
Session didUpdate CA831DB2-E078-45C3-9A1C-44F8459AA04F 0.05000613
renderer didUpdate CA831DB2-E078-45C3-9A1C-44F8459AA04F 0.05070856
Session didUpdate CA831DB2-E078-45C3-9A1C-44F8459AA04F 0.05031016
Session didUpdate CA831DB2-E078-45C3-9A1C-44F8459AA04F 0.05070856
renderer didUpdate CA831DB2-E078-45C3-9A1C-44F8459AA04F 0.05118915
Session didUpdate CA831DB2-E078-45C3-9A1C-44F8459AA04F 0.05093153
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it is my problem, because my mobile phone is iPhoneX, it is A11 chip, multi-face recognition is not supported.
The reason for this problem is that I used the iOS13 Beta 1 system at the time, but the maximum number of face recognitions supported during the run was 3, but only one person was actually supported. When I upgraded to iOS13 Beta 2, the update was shown to be the correct one.

Comment: Hey is your code working correctly? I am able to track multi faces but when I try to change 3D model, it's only working with newly detected face.